# How to generate a hash for firefox xpi file?

Tags: javascript, firefox, hash, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to inline install firefox extension. In the example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Installing_Extensions_and_Themes_From_Web_Pages) It needs to have hash of the extension .xpi file. They recomend to use [nslCryptoHash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsICryptoHash).

The first problem is that the code from the CryptoHash is not working. The firefox throws undefined on Components.classes.

The second problem is that how to do hash on a file which I don't have access in browser?

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to look at the WebExtension documentation as it is now the way to implement Firefox Addons/extensions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions

There is a bunch of misleading docs in the site, not all of them are reviewed and/or complete.

Through the new documentation you may see references to the `web-ext` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-ext) tool which helps you on building the `.xpi` file, both for development and production - the last including a way to sign the file with a valid Mozilla's certificate so you can distribute the extension.